# Transfer data between Windows 10 universal app and arduino via bluetooth

Tags: c#, bluetooth, arduino, windows-phone

I want to transfer data (e.g. `int[]`) from Windows 10 universal app to arduino device using bluetooth. Also, I want to send data from arduino to my windows phone app (e.g. `int`).
How could I do that?

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Simple guide:

Step 1:
Locate a Bluetooth shield compatible with your arduino.

Step 2:
Locate example source code for this specific bluetooth shield and try to run it.

Step 3:
Read the documentation and learn how to transmit an array element-by-element.

Step 4:
Read the documentation for using the windows 10 bluetooth API.

Step 5:
Locate example code for establishing a connection from the windows 10 bluetooth api and try to run it.

Step 6: Use step 3 and 5 together for the desired result.